# iOS5 - Storyboard - showing another view

Tags: iphone, storyboard, ios5

This is simple one though:
I'm having XCode 4.2 with iOS beta7. I am just trying a to have to views with one button in first view. On click of button, it will show next view.
In many tutorials, when I click and drag the button to next view, it will show "performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:" view.
But in my interface builder, its showing "Storyboard Segues with Push, Modal, Popover, Custom......"
I don't know whether I'm doing wrong or its the behavior of the xcode itself....
can some one suggest me good tutorials for iOS5 storyboard please?

Comment: You should watch the session on storyboards from wwdc 2011: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

Comment: Please refer to this site: http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html

Comment: Actually on seeing that website itself, I got confused......

Comment: Not a good reference at all. Doesn't not match the release version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you doing everything right. Push, Modal are types of showing next screen (UIView). You need to select it according Human Interface Guidelines from Apple.